# migrating postgresql lc_ctype cluster values do not match

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, homebrew, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.0

Having to migrate a postgresql cluster within the homebrew framework (following instructions here), 
https://gist.github.com/cjolly/2870054
the migration fails upon command

> pg_upgrade -d /usr/local/var/postgres-9.0.4/ -D
>   /usr/local/var/postgres -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/bin -B
>   /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin

with error

> lc_ctype cluster values do not match:  old "UTF-8", new "C"

any idea how to overcome this?

Alternatively, I'm willing to remain with version 9.0.4 as it was, except I stupidly removed the original Cellar directory, had homebrew do the cleanup (I can confirm it is effective AND dangerous) and was left without any recipe for that version applicable.  I did have the tarball lying around and managed to install that, but it is *not* under homebrew and fear more hair-pulling later on.

I've moved the /usr/local/pgsql/ generated from the tarball to /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/

Any wrong step here?

Answer (score 3):

Solved this issue by specifying --lc-ctype directly when initializing new db:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.4 -E utf8 --lc-ctype=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Running with `LC_CTYPE = C` is generally a really bad idea. Doubly so if you're using the `SQL_ASCII` pseudo-encoding.

If there's no data in the new datadir, I'd recommend deleting it and re-`initdb`'ing with sensible locale and character set options.

Comment: AFAIK, that LC-CTYPE got generated in an automated (or unconscious) manner.  My guess is that this got generated from the 'brew upgrade postgresql' command.  Examining the source databases, they are all created LC_CTYPE='UTF-8' (as the error message attests).  Any idea how the new datadir would be configured as 'C'? or better yet how to have it set to utf8 given homebrew (as per link above) ?